# How to get data from nested JSON?

Tags: java, arrays, json, list, gson

Here's my code:

```
public class Parser {
private static final String PATH = "try.json";


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {

    String req = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(PATH), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    Bean data = new Gson().fromJson(req, Bean.class);
```

```
public class Bean{
    private List<Data> data;

    public List<Data> getData() {
        return data;
    }



public class Data {


    private List<String> urls;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String picture;

    public List<String> getUrls() {
        return urls;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getPicture() {
        return picture;
    }

}
```

Here's dummy-JSON:

```
{
    "data": [
      {
            "urls": [
            "https://google.com",
            "https://googl.com"
            ],
            "name": "Google",
            "type": "corp",
            "picture": "https://google.img"
      },
      {
            "urls": [
            "https://yandex.ru"
            ],
            "name": "Yandex",
            "type": "corp",
            "picture": "https://yandex.jpg"
      }
    ]
}
```

So main mission here - create the individual objects from json with "name" field and "urls" ArrayList in them, so then I'll add them in another list and get the info by index.
But I just can't understand, how can I make that. Response, for example, for first object probably should looks like that:

```
Google
"https://google.com",
"https://googl.com"
```

Comment: Does this compile? What is JsonRootBean? Should that say Bean? And if so, what issues are you having accessing `data.getData().get(0)`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer yeah, thanks, I miss in renaming from JsonRootBean to Bean. Yes, it compile. And with data.getData().get(0) I get something like that:
$Data@57829d67
So I think I need to override toString, or how else can I extract the parameters, which I need?

Comment: Yes, toString, but you'd continue using the getter methods for both the name and urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want a loop

```
 Bean data = new Gson().fromJson(req, Bean.class);
 for (Data d : data.getData()) {
   System.out.println(d.getName());
   for (String u : d.getUrls()) {
     System.out.println(u);
   }
 }
```

Otherwise, you can already access things by index

```
Data first = data.getData().get(0);
System.out.println(first.getName()); // google
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if the use of GSON is not mandatory for you, you could use Jackson.

With the use of `@JsonProperty` annotation, you could get the nested fields, you coudl also add some aliases with `@JsonAlias` if needed.

Here is a short example:

```
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

    public class Data {


    private List<String> urls;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String picture;

    public List<String> getUrls() {
        return urls;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getPicture() {
        return picture;
    }

}
    @JsonProperty("ParentObject") //Here it looks like the parent object is an element of the array Data, so i would treat you Json object as a list of objects and iterate over each.
    private void getFieldNestedValues(Map<String, String> field) {
        urls = field.get("nestedField1"); //nestedField1 would be urls in your case
        name = field.get("nestedField2"); // nestedField2 could be the name for instance
    }
```

I'm pretty sure you could do the same with Gson, hope this sample gives you an idea, of how you could make it work.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I would use an `ObjectMapper` from the Jackson library, to parse and build the object:

```
 JsonNode rootNode = objectMapperProvider.buildSureObjectMapper().readTree(jsonBody);

 YourObject yourObject= objectMapperProvider.buildSureObjectMapper().readValue(rootNode.toString(), YourObject.class);
```

With a custom ObjectMapper for instance:

```
 public ObjectMapper buildSureObjectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
            .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
            .registerModule(new GuavaModule())
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true)
            .setSerializationInclusion(NON_ABSENT);
}
```

Comment: looks much harder, than other variant, but also interesting, I'll try also with that, thanks!

Comment: It's true that is a bit more complicated as I used this solution whend I had to treat some  really complex Json objects that I wanted to serialize.
But it's good to know you can do things many ways